# How to sell planimals in Monster Harvest?

Tags: monster-harvest

The planimals in my pen are shown with monetary values. So how could I sell them to make room for new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interact with the planimal pen, you will see there is a dollar sign next to the planimals in the pen. Click this and you will sell them. You won’t get as much money from these as you do with livestock in the barn but it is another way to sell the planimals to make some money

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!